# How to render a variable in HAML and preserve white-spaces?

Tags: html, ruby, haml

This is what I'm doing:

```
%pre
  =var
```

The value of `var` is `"foo\nbar"`. I'm getting this HTML:

```
<body>
  <pre>foo
  bar</pre>
</body>
```

Obviously, I'm expecting:

```
<body>
  <pre>foo
bar</pre>
</body>
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your `var` on the same line where your `%pre` is. So it looks like `%pre= var`

Answer (score 1):

If you use [ugly mode](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#ugly-instance_method) then you shouldn’t have this problem. Note that in (the hopefully coming soon) Haml 5 [there only is ugly mode](https://github.com/haml/haml/pull/894), so this is probably the best option for the future.

This would produce:

```html
<body>
<pre>foo
bar</pre>
</body>
```

---

For current versions, in non-ugly mode, if you wanted to preserve whitespace like this then normally you would use [`~`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#tilde), which would call [`find_and_preserve`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#find_and_preserve-instance_method) on the result. However here you are already in a `pre` block, and so that won’t work (arguably this is a bug, but with the removal of non-ugly mode in Haml 5 I can’t see any benefit of fixing it).

You could use [`preserve`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#preserve-instance_method) directly though:

```haml
%body
  %pre
    =preserve(var)
```

This produces:

```html
<body>
  <pre>foo&#x000A;bar</pre>
</body>
```

which has the same affect as your desired result when rendered.